# Help with jQuery append/prepend selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have html like so:

```
<div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

How would I insert some text before before the last span?
Like this:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
new text
    <span></span>
```

I have `$("div span:last").prev().append("new text");`
which puts the new text inside a span tag.

**Note:** The number of span tags inside of the div tag can change dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.prepend()` and `.append()` are functions used for inside insertion. You are probably looking for either `.before()` or `.after()`, which are functions for outside insertions that will insert into the DOM at the same DOM level of the found selector.